# adding new row to data grid view in c# application

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to add an empty row with multiple columns in an empty data grid view.
Basically data grid view control does not have any query or any data attached(on form load or data source).
My grid view look like below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `DataTable` to do this.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
        dt.Columns.Add("Column2");
        dt.Columns.Add("Column3");
        dt.Columns.Add("Column4");
        dt.Columns.Add("Column5");
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; //if dataGridView1 is your DataGridView
```